# Outlook 2010 Addin works when built in Debug configuration but does not work in Release configuration

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, add-in

I've built, installed and used an Outlook Addin successfully that was built in Debug configuration, but when I change to Release configuration and rebuild, the install still works, but when I open Outlook the addin is not loaded.

I open Options \ Addins and my addin appears Disabled.  I try to enable it but it won't work.

How do I see what is stopping the addin from loading?  Are there log files somewhere I can check?

I've open Project Properties for the Debug and Release configs but can't see any difference.
Can anyone offer suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your add-in is on list check if you add-in is not in disabled add-in list. These add-ins can be found in the same combo as Addins COM. If it is there, remove it from there (by enabling it). Then You will be able to enable it on Addins COM list.

Comment: Thanks Marcin!  didn't know to look there